# Is there a way to highlight selected element by parent attribute?

Tags: css

The classic way of a list element selection is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>elem 1</li>
    <li class="selected">elem 2</li>
    <li>elem 3</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to select element using only CSS like this:

```
<ul data-id="2">
    <li data-id="1">elem 1</li>
    <li data-id="2">elem 2</li>
    <li data-id="3">elem 3</li>
</ul>
```

Can I make a CSS selector which will apply to a child having some attribute matching with the parent one?

Let's imagine, that we don't know elements' IDs before, because if we know and there are a few of them, we can just write such CSS rules:

```
ul[data-id=1] li[data-id=1],
ul[data-id=2] li[data-id=2],
ul[data-id=3] li[data-id=3] {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and this should work

But I need a solution for unknown IDs.

Comment: CSS only? No. JavaScript? Sure.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, Javascript way is very simple, right. but I hope there is a CSS way )

Comment: CSS only - if ure page is ajax designed u can use checkboxes as "links" and set the css to :checked for "selected" state and loads the page with ajax... only a workaround and not really recommended, but should work - css only without "browser-hacks"? no - like @MarcinJuraszek said

Comment: There is no way to do that in CSS alone, since CSS doesn't provide backreferences or methods to compare classes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how are you going to update the selection's `data-id` of the `<ul>`? If it is by Javascript, make it already update the list item then...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot implement this through css. Here when SASS comes to the rescue.
Get to know about [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) here..

```
@for $i from 1 through 3
ul[data-id=#{$i}] li[data-id=#{$i}]{
  font-weight: bold
}
```

Comment: you mean something more like `@for $i from 1 through {MaxInteger}` ;) Even that will only work for integers, not strings. Imagine, how large that file can get?

Comment: thanks for an idea, but this will not cover ALL UNKNOWN cases of children ids

Comment: No that will create unnecessary css rules. So its better you set a limit. However, This will create a relation between parent and child selectors.

Comment: The best way to do this is to use jQuery and write a rule that will  add classes to parent and children accordingly.

Comment: @SwastikPareek You didn't understand what I meant. The only way to make sure this works without knowing the ids (the OP stated that he/she doesn't know) is to add every possible ID, my comment is just explaining how that's not feasible

Comment: @JuanMendes: But dont you think jQuery is the best way to do it ?

Comment: @SwastikPareek No, I don't think you need jQuery, plain JavaScript will do ;) I'm sure the OP knows you can do it with JavaScript/jQuery. My point is that the code you posted in your answer is not very useful